# Wifi drivers are horrible... (88X2bu)

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a wifi dongle with a 88x2bu chipset and morrownr's drivers dont work, i downloaded the newest one to check if it works and it showed the networks but i couldnt connect to them even if i entered the password, it wanted the password over and over again even though i entered it correctly, https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702 this is where i installed the drivers from, i did exactly what it wanted it me to do, i tried his old drivers before and they were even worse, i cant switch to ubuntu because of this reason, theres no good drivers for this chipset and dont recommend me to buy a new wifi dongle, i dont want to pay money to use a free os.

Is there anyone with the 88x2bu chipset with a working driver? If so please send me it.

Comment: All I see here is a complaint, not anything actionable.  Do you have an actual question?  If not, then this isn't really a question as written.

Comment: oh my bad i forgot to say "does anyone know a good driver"

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the post to include the script results, we may be able to tweak some settings

Comment: Basic starting point is what OS/release you're using; and we don't currently know that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your device is identified like this in `lsusb` output:

```
0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu
```

Then you just need an OS with an updated 6.2 Linux kernel. It's provided out-of-the-box by Ubuntu 22.04.3 or 23.04.